# Am I even using Exuberant ctags?

Tags: unix, vim, ctags

After downloading and installing exuberant ctags, I get some issues hinting that the ctags shell command isn't corresponding to my newly installed ctags.

```
Directory_of_Scripts$ ctags
usage: ctags [-BFadtuwvx] [-f tagsfile] file ...
Directory_of_Scripts$ ctags -R
ctags: illegal option -- R
usage: ctags [-BFadtuwvx] [-f tagsfile] file ...
```

Apparently the ctags i'm using does not have the option to collect files recursively (-R option) and it wants a file as an argument; the current exuberant ctags, ctags command can be called without parameters/arguments, it will simply act on the current directory.

I really need help here, I just started trying to associate myself with Vim (its very nice btw); and I'm wanting to extend functionality to make it recognize source code better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like OSX ctags to me. Shouldn't take you more than a couple minutes to grab [exuberant ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) and get it installed. Then it'll work like you expect.

Answer (score 1):

just simply copy the ctags in `/usr/local/bin` to cover the ctags in `/usr/bin` .. and then you can use it...

This is exactly what I just tried and it succeed